# How to reselect item in Telerik's RadGrid?

Tags: telerik-grid

I have 2 Telerik's rad grids. First one is master and second one is detail. I can delete rows from both grids independently by pressing "Delete" button on toolbar above each grid. I also have "Refresh" buttons in toolbar of both grids.

The problem is with detail grid. When I delete item(s) the grid doesn't refresh. Calling Rebind method doesn't help. The only thing that helps is to press "Refresh" button in toolbar of master grid and select the row in master grid by mouse that was previously selected. After that I can see refreshed detail grid.

So, I don't need to press "Refresh" button in toolbar of master grid and select the row in master grid by mouse. I can refresh the master grid programmatically and only want to reselect the item that was originally selected also programmatically. I've tried this:

item.Selected = true;

But, it only visually selects the item in master grid and doesn't refresh the detail grid.

So, how to select the item in master grid programmatically in order to get the same effect as selecting it by mouse?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised that your probably using different DataSource for both grids, but pointing to the same database, right? My example below uses the same datasource for both grids. However I made on a detail view versus a normal view by making some columns not visible. Maybe this strategy could fix your issue?

My first thought was to try implement the SelectionChanged event, or if not that, the SelectionChanging event. Put a refresh in there you see. But I didn't end up doing it that way.

I wrote a small program as below. It saves the edits to disk with any row change as long as its not a remove (I had trouble saving remove edits when the button was clicked it gave a null pointer exception on the remove command). It also saves changes just before closing the program (so that any delete rows are also saved then). I did find that the deleteOne and deleteTwo buttons (that delete from the first or second grid, respectively) do in fact cause the deletion to occur in both grids. So a possibility is you could use the radGridView1.Rows.Remove(row) or RemoveAt(i) command if that works in your situation?

Another possibility is that if refresh isn't working you could set the DataSource to null and then set it to the data source again, after deleting the row. This is a bit drastic but if it's the only thing that works? I'm talking about the data source for both grids.

My code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Telerik.WinControls;
using Telerik.WinControls.Data;
using Telerik.WinControls.UI;

namespace RadControlsWinFormsApp1
{
public partial class RadForm1 : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
{
    public RadForm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void RadForm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'testdbDataSet.Customers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.customersTableAdapter.Fill(this.testdbDataSet.Customers);
        radGridView1.Columns["Address"].IsVisible = false;
    }

    private void radGridView1_RowsChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // if removing don't update, because if my delete button is pressed this
        // will otherwise cause all sorts of problems and freezes the grid
        if (e.Action != NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            try
            {
                customersTableAdapter.Update(testdbDataSet);
            }
            catch (DBConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                // unable to save right now, don't worry about it
            }
        }
        radGridView2.Refresh();
    }

    private void butDeleteOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool haveRemoved = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < radGridView1.Rows.Count && !haveRemoved; ++i)
        {
            GridViewRowInfo row = radGridView1.Rows[i];
            if (row.IsSelected)
            {
                haveRemoved = true;
                radGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    private void butDeleteTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool haveRemoved = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < radGridView2.Rows.Count && !haveRemoved; ++i)
        {
            GridViewRowInfo row = radGridView2.Rows[i];
            if (row.IsSelected)
            {
                haveRemoved = true;
                radGridView2.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void radGridView2_RowsChanged(object sender, GridViewCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // if removing don't update, because if my delete button is pressed this
        // will otherwise cause all sorts of problems and freezes the grid
        if (e.Action != NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            try
            {
                customersTableAdapter.Update(testdbDataSet);
            }
            catch (DBConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                // unable to save right now, don't worry about it
            }
        }
        radGridView1.Refresh();
    }

    private void RadForm1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // ensure all data is saved back into database on close
        customersTableAdapter.Update(testdbDataSet);
    }
    //private void radGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellEventArgs e)
    //{
    //}
}
}
```